# Access $rootScope and $scope inside `$rootScope.$on`

Tags: angularjs

I need to set the $rootScope.VARIABLE when the URL changed.

How could I do that inside $rootScope.$on callback?

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
    $rootScope.alert =True; // $rootScope is undefined
});
```

Comment: *"$rootScope is undefined"*. This is absolutely **not possible** given that `$rootScope.$on` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code withing **myApp.run** context.

```js
myApp.run(["$rootScope", "$window", "$location",function ($rootScope, $window, $location) {
 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
  $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
 });
 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
  $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
 });
}]);
```